# query phone number with different format in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's a table named "Person" with attribute id as primary key and phone_number which is from user input so they are formatted in different ways. I need query the id with phone number. 
For example, Person.where(:phone_number => 4155332321)
However, the number in the model could be 415-533-2321 or 4155332321. How could I write the query for that?
BTW, I can't change the phone number format in the model. Otherwise, I can convert the phone in the query and model to be the same format.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a two-part approach to this.

First, you'll want to also save a "normalized" phone number to the database. This contains no formatting at all -- just numbers. This will require you to add a new column to your database, say, `normalized_phone_number` and write a `before_save` callback to store this value.

```rb
class Person
  before_save :normalize_phone_number

  def self.normalize_number(number)
    number.gsub(/[^\d]/, '') if string.present?
  end

  def normalize_phone_number
    self.normalized_phone_number = Person.normalize_number(self.phone_number)
  end
end
```

Next, you'll want to write a custom class method to find the person based on a normalized number from user input. Your `Person` class will now include:

```rb
class Person
  def self.with_normalized_phone_number(phone_number)
    where(normalized_phone_number: normalize_number(phone_number)).first
  end
end
```

You could also write `Person.with_normalized_phone_number` as an ActiveRecord scope, which would be my preference, but ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)